# multiple taps are required to activate ontapgesture

Tags: ios, swiftui

so I'm writing an app with swiftUI, and I'm having an issue where I have to tap (or rather click) multiple times in the simulator for the exclamation point image (report), and anything on the menu (edit/delete).

I'm new-ish to this, and haven't been able to figure out why it isn't working as it should.

```
struct NoteView: View {
@State private var isShowingMenu = false
@State private var isEditNote = false
@State private var isReporting = false
@State private var isShowingDeleteConfirmation = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            HStack (spacing: 20) {
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark")
                    .font(.system(size: 24))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isReporting.toggle()
                    }
            }
        }
    }.toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            if isAuthorized {
                Button(action: {
                    isShowingMenu = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isEditNote) {
                    // Present the edit form
                    EditNoteFormView(note: note, isEditMode: $isEditNote)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .actionSheet(isPresented: $isShowingMenu) {
        // Define the menu options for the user
        ActionSheet(title: Text("Menu"), buttons: [
            .default(Text("Edit"), action: {
                isEditNote.toggle()
            }),
            .destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {
                isShowingDeleteConfirmation.toggle()
            }),
            .cancel()
        ])
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $isShowingDeleteConfirmation) {
        Alert(
            title: Text("Delete Note"),
            message: Text("Are you sure you want to delete this note?"),
            primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete"), action: {
                // Call the deleteNote function passing the note.id
                deleteNote(noteID: note.id)
                dismiss()
            }),
            secondaryButton: .cancel()
        )
    }
    .alert(isPresented: $isReporting) {
        Alert(
            title: Text("Report Note"),
            message: Text("Are you sure you want to report this note?"),
            primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Report"), action: {
                // Call the reportNote function passing the userID and noteID
                firestoreManager.reportNote(userID: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, noteID: note.id)
                dismiss()
            }),
            secondaryButton: .cancel()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Refrain from using ZStack? Views are stacked on top of each other, maybe at some point there is a touch point overlap.